# Moving image leaving trail and directional movement according to mouse position -Processing

Tags: processing

So I managed to make most of the exercise but can't think of a way to make the trail of the moving image. Also, in the video ball moves in the direction of mouse position.

However, when I tried to do that, mouse position is changing every time and the ball is following the mouse while moving. The velocity had to be calculated using the mouse position. Any help would be appreciated.

This is how it should look: https://streamable.com/9jdc3

My code:

```java
PImage ball, bFire;
int xPosB, yPosB, bW, bH, bFW, bFH, velocityX, velocityY;
boolean bMoving;

void setup() {
  size(1024, 512);

  //loading images
  ball = loadImage("ball.png");
  bFire = loadImage("ballFire.png");

  //resizing images
  ball.resize(ball.width/4, ball.height/4);
  bFire.resize(bFire.width/4, bFire.height/4);

  //starting values
  //ball
  xPosB = width/2;
  yPosB = height/2;
}
void draw() {
  background(0);

  //draw ball
  imageMode(CENTER);
  image(ball, xPosB, yPosB);

  //draw fire ball
  if (bMoving) {
    image(bFire, xPosB, yPosB);
    xPosB+=velocityX;
    yPosB+=velocityY;
  }

  //colision detection
  if (xPosB-bFire.width/2 <= 0 || xPosB+bFire.width/2 >= width) {
    velocityX*=-1;
  } else if (yPosB-bFire.height/2 <= 0 || yPosB+bFire.height/2 >= height) {
    velocityY*=-1;
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  if (mouseButton == LEFT) {
    bMoving=!bMoving;
    velocityX = mouseX/100;
    velocityY = mouseY/100;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't repoduce the problem you describe - of the ball following the mouse.

I can tell you that the `mousepressed()` you use is incorrect.
You assign the velocity, but because mouseX and mouseY will always be positive the ball will always move to the right and down.

Try the code below, it sets the velocity to the difference between the mouse and the current position of the ball. The ball will now always move towards the mouse.

```
void mousePressed() {
  if (mouseButton == LEFT) {
    bMoving=!bMoving;
    velocityX = (mouseX - xPosB) / 50;
    velocityY = (mouseY - yPosB) / 50;
  }
```

Second point: I don't know how your ballFire.png looks, but right now it is drawn at the exact same X/Y location of the ball. This cannot give you a trailing effect, for that you'll have to draw the fireball a little behind the ball.

Try the code below:

```
//draw fire ball
  if (bMoving) {
    image(bFire, xPosB-velocityX, yPosB-velocityY);
    xPosB+=velocityX;
    yPosB+=velocityY;
  }

  //draw ball
  imageMode(CENTER);
  image(ball, xPosB, yPosB);
```

It draws the fireBall behind the ball based on the velocity. So faster means more distance. You can tweak this distance of course. If you want multiple firballs as trailing effect, draw the fireball multiple times with different offsets.

Final note: you'll want to draw the ball last, else the fireball will be drawn half over the normal ball.

Comment: The fire ball has to replace the basic ball and leave a trail that looks like the fire ball image's blurred version. These are the photos of balls: ibb.co/tJ687xk ibb.co/fkpXv46